# How to check if LOG4J file appender is closed?

Tags: log4j, fileappender

How can I check if LOG4J file appender is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the property [*closed*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html#closed) on the specific appender. Since *closed* is a protected  field, you may need to set it visible before accessing using java reflection.

Comment: How can I do it using reflections?